# Python keep score even after loop

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have a question. My code has a def main(): and I want to keep the score even after the user inputs to restart. The problem is that the score becomes 100 again after the loop. How can I fix this?

```
import random
print("Welcome to Python Acey Ducey Card Game")
print()
print("Acey-ducey is played in the following manner: the dealer (computer) deals two cards faced up and you have an option to bet or not bet depending on whether or not you feel the card will have a value between the first two. If you do not want to bet, enter a $0 bet.")
print()
def main():
  bankbalance = 100
  print("These cards are open on the table:")
  print()
  print("First card:")
  firstcard = random.randint(1,13)  
  print(firstcard)
  print("Second card:")
  secondcard = random.randint(1,13)
  print(secondcard)
  playerinput = input("Enter your bet: ") 
  playerinput = int(playerinput)  
  dealercard = random.randint(1,13)
  dealercard = int(dealercard)
  print("The card you drew was", (dealercard), "!")
  if dealercard > firstcard and dealercard < secondcard or dealercard < firstcard and dealercard > secondcard:
    print("You win!")
    bankbalance = bankbalance + playerinput
    print("You currently have $", (bankbalance))
    playagain = input("Would you like to play again yes/no: ")
    if playagain == ("yes"):
      main()
    else:
      exit
  else:
    print("You lost!")
    bankbalance = bankbalance - playerinput
    print("You currently have $", (bankbalance))
    playagain = input("Would you like to play again yes/no: ")
    if playagain == ("yes"):
      main()
    else:
      exit
main()
```

Comment: You'd be better off writing an explicit loop and not using recursion. Recursion is not a goto.

Comment: @khelwood I'm not that sure what you mean, and if this helps, I'm a noob, so if you could clarify things further that would help!

Comment: Simplistically, figure out all the stuff that you want to happen multiple times, and put it all in a block with `while True:` at the top. When you want to exit the loop, put a `return` or `break`.

Comment: Ah, that also makes sense. I'll try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the score as a global variable, outside of `main` :

```
bankbalance = 100
def main():
  global bankbalance
  print("These cards are open on the table:")
  # ....
```

edit: I know that there are better ways to implement what the OP wants. My goal though is to help him improve his own code, by explaining to him what was the problem in the first place with it, so as to help the OP learn from his mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) pointed out in the comments, it would be better to actually loop than to recur in this case. If you call `main` inside of `main`, you're going ever deeper and deeper into nested function calls, when you don't need to. A `while` loop lets you keep doing something until a condition is no longer true. And a function can both accept arguments and return a value, which lets the game start from a different balance each time.

I've made a few other tweaks. I've rewritten your win/loss check with chained `<` comparisons and split them onto two lines for readability. Inside parentheses, you can add line breaks without affecting code execution. Python automatically combines strings that are broken up this way, too, hence what I did for the intro text. I've also altered some of the variable-printing to use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

```py
import random

def main():
    print("Welcome to Python Acey Ducey Card Game")
    print()
    print("Acey-ducey is played in the following manner: the dealer "
          "(computer) deals two cards faced up and you have an option "
          "to bet or not bet depending on whether or not you feel the "
          "card will have a value between the first two. If you do not "
          "want to bet, enter a $0 bet.")
    
    bankbalance = 100
    playagain = "yes"
    
    while playagain == "yes":
        bankbalance = play(bankbalance)
        playagain = input("Would you like to play again yes/no: ")
    
    print(f"You leave with ${bankbalance}")


def play(bankbalance):
    print()
    print(f"You currently have ${bankbalance}")
    print("These cards are open on the table:")
    print()
    print("First card:")
    firstcard = random.randint(1,13)    
    print(firstcard)
    print("Second card:")
    secondcard = random.randint(1,13)
    print(secondcard)
    playerinput = input("Enter your bet: ") 
    playerinput = int(playerinput)    
    dealercard = random.randint(1,13)
    print(f"The card you drew was {dealercard}!")
    if (firstcard < dealercard < secondcard or
        secondcard < dealercard < firstcard
    ):
        print("You win!")
        return bankbalance + playerinput
    else:
        print("You lost!")
        return bankbalance - playerinput

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, note that your code, currently, lets you bet more than you have, and keep going once you're negative. If that's not intentional, think about how you might avoid that.

Comment: I see your point. Also, I have found out that the amount can go negative and bid more than you have, and I'm kinda lost over there.

Comment: I've tried to make an elif as shown below but not finding that resolving the issue. I typed yes and tried to bet larger again and it still allows me.

elif playerinput > (bankbalance):
    print("You cannot bet more than you have!")
    playagain = input("Would you like to play again yes/no: ")
    if playagain == ("yes"):
      main()
    else:
      exit

Comment: If, after reading and experimenting, you're unable to get that part to work, I'd advise asking a new, separate question about it.

Comment: Interesting. Stack Overflow only allows me  to post every 90 minutes. I'll post when the timer is off.

Comment: Perhaps take the time to try it out more yourself, and search (on Google and/or here on SO) for things like Python conditionals and control flow. You might figure something out! Asking a new question should be one of your last options, not your first.

Comment: Yeah. That's pretty much what I'm doing now. I've fixed the betting over the amount you have, but having negative amount of money is my current problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished a similar solution to above.  The recursive call will be noticeable after playing 2 or more rounds.

```
import random

def welcome():
    print("Welcome to Python Acey Ducey Card Game\n")
    print("Acey-ducey is played in the following manner: ")
    print("\tthe dealer (computer) deals two cards faced up")
    print("\tyou have an option to bet or not bet depending on")
    print("\twhether or not you feel the card will have a value")
    print("\tbetween the first two.")
    print("\tIf you do not want to bet, enter a $0 bet.\n")


def get_bet(balance):
    while True:
        bet = input("Enter your bet: ")
        try:
            bet = int(bet)
            if bet <= balance and bet >= 0:
                return bet
            elif bet < 0:
                print("You can't bet negative amounts!")
            else:
                print("You don't have enough cash to bet that!")
        except:
            print("You must enter a number bet!")
        
    

def game_round(bankbalance):
    print("\nThese cards are open on the table:")
    firstcard = random.randint(1,13)
    print("\nFirst card:", firstcard)
    secondcard = random.randint(1,13)
    print("Second card:", secondcard)
    playerinput = get_bet(bankbalance) 
    dealercard = random.randint(1,13)
    dealercard = int(dealercard)
    print("The card you drew was", (dealercard), "!")
    if dealercard > firstcard and dealercard < secondcard or dealercard < firstcard and dealercard > secondcard:
        print("You win!")
        return playerinput
    else:
        print("You lost")
        return -playerinput


def main():
    welcome()
    bankbalance = 100
    print("You currently have $", (bankbalance))
    while True:
        playagain = input("Enter [Y] to play a game, any other key to exit: ")
        if playagain.lower() == ("y"):
            bankbalance = game_round(bankbalance)
            print("\nYou currently have $", (bankbalance))
        else:
            break
    print("Thanks for playing- Goodbye!")

main()
```

Comment: @Strattigan Your code still has the problem of going into negatives... Same problem I'm stuck on.

Comment: @AndrewLiu it will not allow negatives now.  Also, one thing to beware of with betting games is to watch out for the user entering a negative value.  
Say I have low odds of winning and I bet -1000000000; this is less than the amount I have, and if I lose, the code might do amount -= bet... so I've won by finding a case that was not checked :)

Comment: @Strattigan, it doesn't go to negatives anymore! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome.  Also, if you are using Python 3.6 or after, the f-string is a really nice way to format your output.